# How reliable are ferries in Puerto Rico?

Tags: ferries, puerto-rico

I will be travelling to Puerto Rico May 28 to June 4. I am going to spend half of my time in San Juan, and the other half in Vieques. From what I have read there can be difficulties in using the ferry from Fajardo to Vieques. Would I be better off paying for a flight to Vieques or are the Ferries reliable?

Comment: What difficulties are we talking about? What do you mean by reliability?